# Type error : list indices must be integers or slices, not dict

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv

I am trying to read json data and writing to csv file but not working. How to approach for it to get my expected output

**Code :**

```
import json
import csv 
import ast


# Using json loads to load data from varaible which holds json data 
jdata = json.loads(data)

# Fetching all headers from json and converting into list   
jkey = list(jdata[0].keys())  

# get length 
glen_count = len(data)


# Looping through the keys to write data to csv file  
for r in range(glen_count):
  for hd in jkey:
    with open("/content/sample_data/abc.csv",'w') as wr:
      csv_wr = csv.DictWriter(wr,fieldnames=jkey)
      csv_wr.writeheader()
      csv_wr.writerows(jdata[jdata[r][hd]])  # error : Type error : list indices must be integers or slices, not dict
```

*My variable `data` contain json*

```
data = '''
[

 {
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fc7897969b8ab14e1cad8f4"
  },
  "m": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
  "t": "o",
  "pId": {
    "$oid": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46"
  },
  "pVal": {
    "title": "Switch",
    "val": 1,
    "status": null,
    "portType": "AC",
    "portIcon": "AC",
    "_id": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46",
    "no": "0",
    "cat": "s",
    "device": {
      "ports": [
        "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46"
      ],
      "_id": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45",
      "macId": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
      "deviceId": "LTAC21220050009",
      "dType": "5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb",
      "createdAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "assignedTo": "5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d"
    },
    "mac": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:57.776Z"
  },
  "dId": {
    "$oid": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
},{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "5fc7897b69b8ab14e1cad8f5"
  },
  "m": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
  "t": "o",
  "pId": {
    "$oid": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46"
  },
  "pVal": {
    "title": "Switch",
    "val": 0,
    "status": null,
    "portType": "AC",
    "portIcon": "AC",
    "_id": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46",
    "no": "0",
    "cat": "s",
    "device": {
      "ports": [
        "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c46"
      ],
      "_id": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45",
      "macId": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
      "deviceId": "LTAC21220050009",
      "dType": "5ee38d3a4afdf74cf8b07dfb",
      "createdAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:15.235Z",
      "updatedAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:36.773Z",
      "__v": 0,
      "assignedTo": "5fc62223f7fa2b262ecb6c2d"
    },
    "mac": "24:6F:28:55:7C:55",
    "__v": 0,
    "createdAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:15.237Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-12-02T12:32:59.951Z"
  },
  "dId": {
    "$oid": "5fc7894ff7fa2b262ecb6c45"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z"
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": "2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z"
  },
  "__v": 0
}

]
```

Expected output is need to write to csv file : column : `id , val , createdAt , updatedAt`

```
id , val , createdAt , updatedAt
5fc7897969b8ab14e1cad8f4 , 0 , 2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z , 2020-12-02T12:32:57.781Z
5fc7897b69b8ab14e1cad8f5 , 0 , 2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z , 2020-12-02T12:32:59.955Z
```

Comment: Hint: The error message says that you are trying to index a list, i.e. you are doing `foo[bar]` where `foo` is a list. Then `bar` must be either an integer or a slice (`start:end`), but in your program, for some reason, it's a dictionary. When debugging it is often useful to split expressions into multiple lines to see at which step things go wrong. It is also useful to add `print` calls, to see what values actually are. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, a few things:

1. `jkey = list(jdata[0].keys())` will give you `jkeys = ['_id', 'm', 't', 'pId', 'pVal', 'dId', 'createdAt', 'updatedAt', '__v']`, which is more than your desired keys. If your goal is to select only `id , val , createdAt , updatedAt`, `jkeys` must reflect that as `jkeys = ['id' , 'val' , 'createdAt' , 'updatedAt']`. It's the value you're passing to the fieldnames, after all. Those are the header names, and it identifies the order in which the values will be written.
2. `glen_count = len(data)` is likely a typo and you meant to write `jdata`, data is the string containing the json data, so you would be counting the length of this string.
3. The error you're going through is because the return of the expression `jdata[jdata[r][hd]]` is `{'$oid': '5fc7897969b8ab14e1cad8f4'}`, a dict. You are using this one as a index for the list `jdata`.
4. About `DictWriter` and `writerows`: You pass to its constructor specific fieldnames, in your case, it's `jkeys = ['id' , 'val' , 'createdAt' , 'updatedAt']`. This is your desired header. You must then either use a list of dictionaries with `writerows` or a single dictionary with `writerow`. `Writerows` will have you write all instances at once, and `writerow` is a single instance at a time. See [CSV File Reading and Writing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#writer-objects) as a reference.
5. Careful with looping through `with open("/content/sample_data/abc.csv",'w') as wr:`, you'll be rewriting your own file! See [Reading and Writing Files](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) to learn about the writing modes!

I will post the following as a solution, using `writerows` to separate the logic of writing to a file and the logic of setting up the rows. Hopefully those are the headers desired. If not, it's easy to change according to your own needs.

```
import json
import csv 
import ast

jdata = json.loads(data)

# Only desired headers 
jkeys = ['id' , 'val' , 'createdAt' , 'updatedAt']

# setting up rows
list_rows = []
for el in jdata:
  dict_jdata = {}
  dict_jdata['id'] = el['_id']['$oid']
  dict_jdata['val'] = str(el['pVal']['val'])
  dict_jdata['createdAt'] = el['createdAt']['$date']
  dict_jdata['updatedAt'] = el['updatedAt']["$date"]
  list_rows.append(dict_jdata)

# Writing to a file  
with open("/content/sample_data/abc2.csv",'w') as wr:
  csv_wr = csv.DictWriter(wr,fieldnames=jkeys)
  csv_wr.writeheader()
  csv_wr.writerows(list_rows)
```

Hopefully this helped :)